# Threaded Server to Receive XML Alerts from Network Sensor

Tags: python, serversocket

I have a network sensor that sends XML alerts that we can then parse out to use for various reasons.  In my case I want to use these alerts to parse out the Alert ID so I can pull a saved item from the sensor itsef that saves in the following format ..

The way I'm planning to handle this is that I'm going to have a server listening on a Linux system and have the sensor send alerts to that system whenever an item I'm interested in, such as a report, is saved on the sensor.

I created a simple socket server in Python, and it accepts incoming connections, but being new to Python I was curious if there was a better way to implement the server.  I've seen some suggestions for using ServerSocket instead of socket, etc.  Just curious from more experienced developers.  I also want to implement a socket timeout, or some other feature to close the socket once there is no more data on that socket.  I've tried socket.settimeout(), but the socket just closes immediately so for now I have a temporary placeholder where I can send "close" from the client to close the socket.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.  The working code is below, beware its dirty since I'm new to Python.

```
from socket import *
import thread

# Server parameters
HOST = ''
PORT = 8000
ADDR = HOST, PORT
BUFF = 4096

def handler(clientsock,addr):
   while 1:
      data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
      if not data:
         break
      clientsock.send(response(data))

      # Closes the connection
      # Temp until I can get timeout to work
      if data.rstrip() == "close":
         break

   clientsock.close()

   print addr, "- closed connection" #log on console

def response(data):
       return 'Data sent: ' + data

if __name__=='__main__':
   server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
   server.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

   try:
      server.bind(ADDR)
      server.listen(5)
   except sock.error as msg:
      print('Unable to bind to ', ADDR)
      print('Error code: ', msg[0])
      print('Message: ', msg[1])

   while 1:
      print 'waiting for connection... listening on port', PORT
      clientsock, addr = server.accept()
      print '...connected from:', addr
      thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, addr))
```

Thanks!

Comment: After some reading perhaps I should be taking advantage of socket.settimeout() or setdefaulttimeout() for the purpose of closing the sockets to prevent congestion?  Also from reading it seems like I should probably use ServerSocket instead of just the socket class.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you need to use objects, to do what you want:

create a socket server:

```
from socket import *
import threading
class ThController( threading.Thread ):

   # Override Thread's __init__ method to accept the parameters needed:
    def __init__( self,parent):
        print 'Init server controller'
        self.port = 4001
        self.server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
        self.server.bind(('localhost', self.port))
        self.server.listen(5)
        self.parent = parent
        threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )

    def run ( self ):
        while self.parent.ctrlattive:
            connection, address = self.server.accept()
            data = connection.recv(1024)
            self.parent.data=data
```

A second class for istantiate object thead:

```
class MainCtrl():
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainCtrl,self).__init__()
        self.data=None
        self.ctrlattive=True
        self.drivectrl=Sctrl.ThController(self)
        self.drivectrl.start()

    def load_data(self):
        #decode data here
        print self.data

test=MainCtrl()
while 1:
  test.load_data()
```

hope this help you

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Admittedly I'm having a hard time understanding your code, and I also can't get it to run without errors.  Doing some reading it looks like I may need to use socket.settimeout()?